# GLSL versions change log?

Tags: opengl, version, glsl

Is there someplace I can read about the changes and additions made in GLSL from version 1.1 to 1.2 and from 1.2 to 1.3?
Google seem to be at a loss for this and I really don't want to start reading the complete specification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Version 1.3](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.30.08.withchanges.pdf) of the spec has differences from 1.2 marked, it also lists changes from 1.2.  [Version 1.2](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.20.8.pdf) has a list of changes from 1.1.