# GLSL -- texture1D is deprecated, what to use instead?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, opengl-3

I'm writing a GLSL shader to #version 130 (OpenGL 3.0)

It gives a warning that "global function texture1D is deprecated after version 120"

I've googled but can't find much. If it's deprecated, then what *should* I be using that provides similar functionality?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494800/glsl-versions-change-log will probably be helpful

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In modern GLSL the deprecated `texture1D/2D/3D/Shadow` functions have been replaced by a general [`texture`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/texture.xml) function (and likewise for the `...Proj` versions and the like) overloaded for all possible sampler types, whose actual dimensionality and type is just determined by the sampler argument. So just leave away the `1D` and you're done.